# Can 'this' argument of an instance method be untyped (i.e. System.Object)?

Tags: c#, cil, reflection.emit

I'm using `System.Reflection.Emit`'s `TypeBuilder` to emit a bunch of custom .NET classes with instance methods. For example:

```
public class EmittedClass
{
    public bool TryGetName(out string value)
    {
        ...
    }

    public bool TryGetAge(out int value)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

All methods follow the same signature that can be described by a generic delegate:

```
public delegate bool TryGetter<T>(out T value);
```

Of course, I'd like be able to explicitly specify the target instance on the call site, like this:

```
var instance = InstanceFactory.CreateInstance();
var tryGetName = InstanceFactory.CreateTryGetter<string>("Name");
string name;
if (tryGetName(instance, out name)) // Problem here.
{
    ...
}
```

For this to work, I need to make the delegate into a so called *open delegate*:

```
public delegate bool TryGetter<T>(object instance, out T value);
```

Since I don't have the compile-time Type of the target instance, I need to pass it as `System.Object`. However, this breaks at runtime, because the instance method expects its 'this' to be of the declaring class's type. Ouch.

The solution I'm currently using is to create an intermediate lambda expression that takes the input object, performs a runtime cast to target type, and then proceeds to invoke the target method. It works, but I feel uneasy about having this kludge in the middle.

**The question is: can I somehow change my emitted methods so that their `this` arguments will accept any `System.Object` and still keep my emitted code verifiable?**

If not, I guess I can still avoid the intermediate lambda by making the methods static and performing the casts in their bodies. Ideally however, I'd like to avoid the casting altogether, but I suspect this can't stand in the managed world due to the way CIL verification and metadata loading work.

Just wondering if someone more knowledgeable about CIL can give me advice on this subject. Thanks!

**UPDATE: The problem I'm trying to solve**

Classes have properties, which are normally backed by fields. This is fine, if instances of said classes are expected to only maintain a single state at a time. With state I mean the combination of values in instance fields at a given time.

My business requirement is to implement an alternative storage to plain fields that will enable a single class instance to have more than one state at the same time. A side goal of this requirement is to make this as efficient as possible, both memory- and speed of access-wise.

The core idea behind my approach is to create a mirror image of the business class using `System.Reflection.Emit` and have the business class maintain a set of those instances, each corresponding to a given state. The getters and setters of the business class then naturally have to be wired to the appropriate methods on the state instance. There are a lot more details involved, but this is the core idea.

I hope the explanation helps understand the reason why I'm asking this question. I appreciate it may seem like over-engineering to many, but other alternatives that involve no `System.Reflection.Emit` are just plain too slow and resource hungry. I can't have that.

Comment: I think you are on to something very interesting. However, you are asking the question backwards. Instead of asking whether a bad solution can be made, ask for a good solution would generate more helpful responses, IMHO

Comment: Point taken. I didn't explain the problem, I'm trying to solve. I'll update my question.

Comment: In response to your edit: what's your actual business problem?  Why do you need an object to have two states at the same time - why not two different objects?

Comment: @Dan: Well, they _are_ two different objects, aren't they? One is the business object, and the other is the state object. But I know what you mean. :) One part of the reason is that the business object also has other properties (not to mention a lot of methods) that have nothing to do with state management. For that, simply reusing the same class for state is not an option. The second part of the reason is that the consumer of business object shouldn't be burdened by multiple objects. It really is just one object to him. The final part of the reason is to avoid the manual boiler plate code.

Comment: @aoven: You've said in your edit "My business requirement is to implement an alternative storage to plain fields that will enable a single class instance to have more than one state at the same time."  That's *not* a business requirement, that's a technical solution to a business requirement.  I can't imagine a reason to prefer reams of `System.Reflection.Emit` code over any amount of boilerplate code - are you sure it's the right answer?

Comment: @Dan: I'm not sure how to respond. Explaining the high-level requirement is hard, because there isn't a single one - there are many. What's important is my observation as an architect of a software solution, that many of our high-level business requirements share certain essential technical patterns. Having a central solution to these would enable a much better overall design. One pattern is state management, but there are also others. Their actual use is quite varied. Suffice to say that Reflection.Emit is very much preferred over tons of boiler plate code, even if you can't imagine it. :)

Comment: @Dan and others: It occurred to me that you may have a bit narrower definition of the term "business requirement" than me. To clarify: I'm not in the business of developing software for your typical end user (ERP, CRM, etc.). I'm in reality building a set of tools for use by _developers_. This means that most of the time, my business requirements boil down to efficient API design and library implementation. Some of the tools in the set actually are compilers. But that's beside the point. I just wanted to clarify it's really not out of place for me to embrace Reflection.Emit and friends. :)

Comment: @aoven: To be honest I still can't conceive of the problem you're trying to solve, or how the code you've posted would be used in practise.  I don't know of an answer to your exact `.Emit` question, but it seems like there must be an alternative solution to the problem (say generics, or extension methods) - without understanding how and why you'll actually *use* this code, it's hard to give an intelligent suggestion.  I still can't understand what you mean by a class with more than one state - because to me, that concept doesn't exist - but I'm intrigued to understand what you're doing.

Comment: @Dan: I appreciate you keep trying to get to the "real problem". It's true that many times, a different approach can avoid the brick wall instead of trying to break it down. Unfortunately, one thing is certain here: _some_ code, _somewhere_, is required. And the only alternatives to having that code emitted by my library are asking my customers (the developers) to either write it themselves or codegen'ing it for them. Using a hypothetical 3rd party library is not an option here, because I can't take dependencies (such is the curse of libraries). And even if I could, it would be a red herring.

Comment: @Dan (continued): I'd like to add that I don't feel like I've painted myself in a corner here. Nor am I hitting a brick wall. The solution I have in place, works, and it is efficient enough to satisfy given business requirements. My question was directed towards finding a way to optimize it, plus maybe learn a few new things about CIL along the way. Coming from a non-managed world of Delphi, it's sometimes a bit frustrating to find how certain safety measures of .NET in reality demand elaborate workarounds to problems that wouldn't even exist, if it weren't for the safety measures themselves.

Comment: @Aoven:  Just because your target audience are developers, doesn't mean you need a complex over-engineered solution.  You say you're seeing a lot of similarity and it sounds like you're trying to provide a single technoligical solution.  However it also sounds like that solution will be way more complex than the orginal problem.  For some reason, architechs seem to enjoy doing this, I haven't figured out why.  The saftey measures in .Net are there for a reason; to prevent common mistakes that cause programs to fail.  Either live with them, or chose a platform that gives you more flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to represent the 'this' type in the delegate signature.

That is given a delegate definition like so:

```
public delegate bool TryGetter<T>(out T value);
```

Any variable of the form:

```
TryGetter<T> x;
```

Can hold either:

1. An instance method on type R with signature `bool Foo(out T value)`, together with an object instance of type R.
2. A static method with signature `static bool Foo(out T value)`
3. A static method with signature `static bool Foo(R object, out T value)` given an object instance of type R.

The third form is called delegate currying, and allows a static method with N+1 arguments to behave as if it was an instance method with N arguments (only the first argument may be curried however).

So, the interface you want is:

```
var instance = InstanceFactory.CreateInstance();
var tryGetName = InstanceFactory.CreateTryGetter<string>(instance,"Name");
```

Then you can do: `tryGetName()` to return the value.

You would probably want to go with case #3, where you generated a `DynamicMethod` with the signature `bool TryGetWhatEver(TheTypeOfInstance obj, out WhatEver x)`, and then create a `TryGetter<WhatEver>`.

---

However I'm still curious as to why you would need to do this. Unless you are dynamically generating big chunks of your app (like rails), this seems like it would be overly complicated.

Comment: Yup. We're definitely talking big chunks here. :)

Answer (score 2):

Considering your requirements wouldn't a library like [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) or [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) reduce all the boilerplate code of copying from one large business object to different state objects? Even if it's not exactly what you want, perhaps they might be of some inspiration for your task.

Comment: Those libraries are solving a different high-level problem, I'm afraid. If anything, I'm actually after the exact _opposite_ of copying values around between objects: I'm trying to keep them in one place (the state object) and redirect to them from other places (the business object, for one). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Reflection.Emit is waaaay overkill for creating an internal storage mechanism to house copies of your property values.  Something as simple as a few Dictionary would be a sufficient way of storing various 'states' of propertyname->value mappings.

Comment: Sure. That was exactly my initial solution. I remember my thoughts at the time quite well: "I know dictionary is a bit wasteful on the memory side. But how bad can it be?" It turned out it can be quite bad. Two dictionaries per type times three types per business object instance on average times a thousand or so business objects in a typical collection amounted to well over 1 MB of memory. Given all the other things that waste memory (legitimately) in a business app, this was entirely unacceptable. Plus a big chunk of performance went straight out the window due to boxing.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `dynamic`:

```cs
dynamic instance = InstanceFactory.CreateInstance();
var tryGetName = InstanceFactory.CreateTryGetter<string>("Name");
string name;

// Should work if “instance” is of the right type *at runtime*
if (tryGetName(instance, out name))
{
    ...
}
```